# React Native nodejs android studio emulator error

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, react-native, android-emulator

I keep Getting this error when i run my react native app via ndroid studio on emulator

[image]

After reloading the page this is what shows up 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your dev server running on http://10.0.0.1:8081
2. check your dev server running status [access http://ip:port(default 8081)]
3. if your ip address is not correct, focus on your emulator, ctrl/cmd + m, dev settings, update your debug server host for device